# Where can I find the aspnetcore Identity UI tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I have made some minor changes to the downloaded Identity scaffolding UI razor page.  I would like to include test for my changes.

Where can I find the Asp.Net Core Razor Identity UI XUnit/NUnit tests?

Comment: You need scaffold Identity UI and make changes to it instead of downloading the UI.

Comment: Sorry about the wording. I added a 'New Scaffolded Item', which added the Identity pages.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean for test now. If you just scaffold the Identity UI, you can just send the request to see the changes of the UI.

Comment: The minor change is I have moved sending out the confirm email message to the user to a static method.  The confirm email message is in numerous pages and is also in my API controller for register user.  The email message can now be changed in one spot.  I would specifically like to test these modified razor pages.

Comment: Microsoft has functional tests of the Identity razor pages.  Start with 
https://source.dot.net/.  From there one can search for what one is trying to find.  The github path is essentially aspnetcore/src/Identity/test/Identity.FunctionalTests/